# Groovy one-liner compilation failure

Tags: groovy

The following Groovy code:

```
1.upTo(5) {println it}
```

Produces this compilation error:

> No signature of method:
>   java.lang.Integer.upTo() is applicable
>   for argument types:
>   (java.lang.Integer,
>   ConsoleScript4$_run_closure1) values:
>   [5,
>   ConsoleScript4$_run_closure1@e83c97]

It appears that the method call matches the signature of [this method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#upto(java.lang.Number%20to,%20groovy.lang.Closure%20closure)), so what's the problem?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.upTo(5) {println it}
```

should be

```
1.upto(5) {println it}
```

(Its an error in case... the "t" should be lower-case in "upto")

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the case on the upto call:

```
groovy -e " 1.upto(5) { println it } "
```